# chrome, javascript is not updating between runs

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, google-chrome, testing

for example, if I were to have `alert("hello world")` during run 1, and then deleted it for run 2, the code would still during the run.

this does not happen in IE, and I don't use firefox so I can't tell if it would happen there.

is chrome for some reason caching my runs and not loading them in on each run?

for reference my project is in .net

Comment: Please post enough code to replicate this with. Not clear what you mean by run or what you are deleting

Comment: The issue isn't within the code, the issue is chrome using old versions of the code rather then the current version.

the hello world was just a sorta example.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should disable the chrome's cache during development.

1.Open your chrome, in its menu , navigate **View** --> **Developer** --> **Developer Tools**

2.In the DevTools panel , click the **Setting** button in the top right .

[image]

3.Check the **Disable cache (while DevTools is open)**

[image]

4.Keep the **DevTools** opend , and refresh your page to check if your new code works.

5.More details about the chrome **DevTools** , refer to [Chrome DevTools Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)